# Clean up unused Dataset, BindingSource & TableAdapter objects

Tags: .net

I have inherited a Winforms project that has several forms with a great deal of Dataset, BindingSource & TableAdapter objects. I am sure that not all of these are required/used.

Is there a way to determine which of these objects are not used by a control (IE dropdown, textbox etc...)?

I am using VS2008

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution would be to go into the designer code (the `Designer.cs` file), right click on the component you're interested in, and select "Find References". This should show you everywhere in the code where this object is used directly.